# Text file processing (read/write) using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with n number of records and each records contains two columns with delimited by tab. I am reading this text file and performing some mapping on the second column using the Powershell scripting. I am able to perform read the text file and able to perform mapping. But when i write the results using set-content command, i am getting below result.

**Input File:**

4803    6000000

4802    6000000

4803    6000000

4803    5000000

**Output File:**

@{Column1=4803; Column2=5000000;}

@{Column1=4802; Column2=6000000;}

@{Column1=4803; Column2=5000000;}

@{Column1=4803; Column2=5000000;}

I am not sure why i am getting Column name in each record. I don't want to see the result like this @{Column1=4803; Column2=5000000;} . But it should be like this - 4803    5000000.  Please could you help me to remove the special character and column names in the output file.

**Expected Result:**

4803    5000000

4802    6000000

4803    5000000

4803    5000000

Script:

```
$fields = Get-Content Temp.txt
$results = @()
foreach($i in $fields)
{
    $field  = $i -split '\t' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
    $field1 = $field[0]
    $field2 = $field[1]
    if ($field1 -eq "4803" -and $field[2].substring(0,2) -eq "60")
        {
            $field2 = "5000000"
        }
    else
        {
            $field2 = $field[1]
        }
            $details = @{       
                    Column1     = $field1
                    Column2     = $field2
                }
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details 
    }
   $results | Select-Object Column1, Column2 | Set-Content -path Temp.txt    [Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your last line of code to use `Format-Table`

```
$results | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Set-Content -path Temp.txt    [Environment]::Exit(0)
```

This should print the data like you expect.

EDIT: Different attempt:

```
$results | ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Column1,$_.Column2 } | Set-Content -path Temp.txt    [Environment]::Exit(0)
```

Comment: By the way: You could import the data by 
Import-Csv Temp.txt -Delimiter ' ' -headers 'Column1', 'Column2'

Comment: I tried with Format-Table -HideTableHeaders. But still getting the same result. Do you think that the Import-csv is the best option to process the text file for this kind of requirement?

Comment: I tried with ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Column1,$_.Column2 } |. It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi.. Please could you help me to group the records. For example, I have one more data filed in the input file. i need to group the records based on Column1 and Column2.

Comment: Open up a new question pls. And mark the answer, if it was helpful